# To enter in decimal format in textbox

Tags: c#

Below code which I am using right now does not give what I require.

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + enteredvalue;
```

I would like to achieve entering decimal value in text box without having to enter "`.`".

If 3 is entered, the output in text box should be `00.03`, and then if `5` is entered the output should be `00.35` and so on.

How do I achieve it?

EDIT: I achieved it by creating a method and calling it everytime i press the input number.

```
   public void dropcashvalue(string inputdigit)
    {
        if (txtDropCash.Text == "00.00")
        {
            txtDropCash.Text = "";
            this.dropstring = "";
        }
        this.dropstring = this.dropstring + inputdigit;
        txtDropCash.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(this.dropstring) / 100).ToString("F2");
    }
```

My textbox and inputnumber design looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain an additional variable for your compund value.

```
double enteredValue = 0.0;
```

Whenever a new digit comes in you *add* it to your value:

enteredValue = enterValue*10 + inputDigit;

Inthe Textbox you show a *formatted* version of your value:

```
textBox.Text = (enteredValue/100).ToString("F2");
```

Comment: thank you @DrKoch.Your code gave way for my requirement.
  public void dropcashvalue(string inputdigit)
        {
            if (txtDropCash.Text == "00.00")
            {
                txtDropCash.Text = "";
                this.dropstring = "";
            }
            this.dropstring = this.dropstring + inputdigit;
            txtDropCash.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(this.dropstring) / 100).ToString("F2");
        } 
I used the above method and called it everytime i press a number.
like dropcashvalue("1"); AND IT WORKED

Comment: Ok will add it @DrKoch